# Pulling data from one sheet to another if

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

My knowledge is pretty basic when it comes to excel and Google Sheets. I'll explain what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to find a way to filter information from 1 sheet to another in Google Sheets. Ideally, I would like to display an entire row if it is a certain colour. If I can't do it by colour then I'd like to display the row if a certain column within the row says **`COMPLETE`**. I have many rows to sort through so I'd really like a way to do this automatically instead of copy and paste.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

take this:

**`=QUERY('Sheet1'!A1:Z; "select * where C = 'COMPLETE'"; 0)`**

- **`Sheet1`** - a name of the sheet from which you want to import
- **`A1:Z`** - the range you want to import
- **`select *`** - select all columns of given range
- **`where C = 'COMPLETE'`** - where in column **C** are cells with word **`COMPLETE`**
- **`0`** - stands for no heading rows (**`1`** for one row, **`2`** for two rows, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

also, you can have this:

**`=FILTER('Sheet1'!A1:Z; C1:C = "COMPLETE")`**

- **`Sheet1`** - a name of the sheet from which you want to import
- **`A1:Z`** - the range you want to import
- **`C1:C = "COMPLETE"`** - filter out only those occurrences which have a given word in column **C**

Answer (score 0):

if you have **two** spreadsheets (two Google Sheets files) you need to use:

**`=IMPORTRANGE("ID or URL"; "'Sheet1'!A1:Z")`**

- **`Sheet1`** - a name of the sheet from which you want to import
- **`A1:Z`** - the range you want to import
- **`"URL"`** - whole URL address of the sheet from which you want to import

  > **example:** **`"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10asxBh4bicmqqGdIIZEguD9ApcJk4GnF82ZiS8MBkq4/edit#gid=1873076661"`**
- **`"ID"`** - part of the URL address of the sheet from which you want to import

  > **example:** **`"10asxBh4bicmqqGdIIZEguD9ApcJk4GnF82ZiS8MBkq4"`**

---

and then you can use **`FILTER`**, **`QUERY`** or both like:

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("10asxBh4bicmqqGdIIZEguD9ApcJk4GnF82ZiS8MBkq4"; "'Sheet1'!A1:Z"); 
        IMPORTRANGE("10asxBh4bicmqqGdIIZEguD9ApcJk4GnF82ZiS8MBkq4"; "'Sheet1'!C1:C") = 
        "COMPLETE")
```

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("10asxBh4bicmqqGdIIZEguD9ApcJk4GnF82ZiS8MBkq4"; "'Sheet1'!A1:Z"); 
 "select * where Col3 = 'COMPLETE'"; 0)
```

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("10asxBh4bicmqqGdIIZEguD9ApcJk4GnF82ZiS8MBkq4"; "'Sheet1'!A1:Z"); 
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("10asxBh4bicmqqGdIIZEguD9ApcJk4GnF82ZiS8MBkq4"; "'Sheet1'!C1:C"); 
  "select *"; 0) = "COMPLETE")
```

**side note:** **`Col3`** - column **strong text** (eg. 3rd column)